# In a functional component how to get a stack trace of the parent component that called child?

Tags: reactjs, parent-child, stack-trace, react-functional-component

Looking to debug a parent and child component, given the example of:

Parent:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

// Child Component
import Bar from './Bar'

const Foo =  (props) => {
  // removed code
  return <Bar data={data} />
}

Foo.propTypes = {
  // code
};

Foo.defaultProps = {
  // code
};

export default Foo;
```

Child:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const Bar =  ({data}) => {
  const stack = React["__SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED"].ReactDebugCurrentFrame.getCurrentStack()
  console.log('stack', stack)
}

Bar.propTypes = {
  // code
};

Bar.defaultProps = {
  // code
};

export default Bar;
```

it doesn't log me the Parent Component name or any info.

### Research

- [Formatting React Stack Trace in the browser as a component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65087566/formatting-react-stack-trace-in-the-browser-as-a-component)
- [Minified component stack trace in create-react-app (dev mode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72535404/minified-component-stack-trace-in-create-react-app-dev-mode)
- [How to use stack trace to find where in the code error is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69440298/how-to-use-stack-trace-to-find-where-in-the-code-error-is)

### Details

```
"react": "^18.2.0",
```

In a React functional component how can I get a trace on what parent called the child component?

Comment: Does `console.trace()` not log the parent component?

Comment: `console.trace()` is giving me the details of the child component and all I need is the component name of the parent component. No where in the trace am I seeing the parent details.

Comment: If you're only looking for the React tree in a particular state of your app for debugging purposes, the [React dev tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en) have a "components" tab which shows an interactive tree, with all the current state and props.

Comment: And if the state you're trying to debug is happening too quickly to have a good look at the tree, you could probably add a `debugger` line in your child component to pause the execution.